# Ionic App not shown in chrome://inspect

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, remote-desktop, chrome-remote-debugging

I am trying to debug my ionic app, running on android device. I tried out google chromee `chrome://inspect` url. But it doesn't give me access to my app. It just shows as given below :-
[image]

It doesn't give any more information. Can anyone plese help me in figuring out, how to counter this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What build commands did you use for deploying the app on the device?

Comment: I have installed the apk on android 4.4.2 device and ran it.

Comment: Does 'adb devices' show tour device Id?

Comment: Yes it's showing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. 
Running `adb server` solved my problem. 
I found the solution here: [Chrome remote debugging, the device is not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371310/chrome-remote-debugging-the-device-is-not-showing-up)

Comment: I have started adb server. Still don't have any luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying **apps directly from the Play Store**. When tried their **debug** version they appeared fine for me.