# Android Studio can't find adb

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio can't find adb. There is also no adb file in sdk folder. I use avast, so I remove adb from it's virus chest and add sdk folder to exclusions. When I'm trying to install Android SDK Platform-Tools, it can't get over step `stopping adb`.

```
To install:
- Android SDK Platform-Tools (platform-tools)
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 27.0.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r27.0.0-windows.zip
Generating patch...
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 27.0.0)" ready.
Finishing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 27.0.0)"
Stopping ADB...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use free antivirus (like Avast, AVG etc) this happens. These free antiviruses assume `adb.exe` file as malicious and delete it immediately when Android Studio starts adb server internally. (I would suggest you not to use any free antivirus. If possible use Windows Defender).

So, first restore `adb.exe` file from antivirus chest. After restoring restart Android Studio by using **File** -> **Invalidate Cache and Restart** -> **Just Restart**

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: No, unfortunately, again unable to locate adb

Comment: If that's case reinstall Android Studio. Or if you don't want to re-install Android Studio read this StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9719158/5180017). And don't forget to turn off or uninstall free antivirus program this time.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for help!